# Freezing of column not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used this fiddle for creating:-
 [fiddle used to make this](http:////jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/bzuasLcz/3/)

But I used list tags to make a table and freeze the first two columns. The first column is getting freeze and second column also but not the header of the second column is getting freeze.
Its working absolutely fine in chrome but not in IE

[Click here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zas4ow3e/)

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px;position:relative;">        
        <ul class="testTable" id="table">
            <div class="testHeader">                    
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>ID</span>
                    <span>Name</span>
                    <span>Description</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                    <span>Details</span>
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="testBody">
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3 a jghasd kahsdk asd ad as das dsadasdasdasdasdas</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
                <li class="testRow">
                    <span>1</span>
                    <span>2</span>
                    <span>3</span>
                    <span>4</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                    <span>5</span>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>       
</div>
```

Please Help

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here first two column are getting freeze [click here - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zas4ow3e/10/).I added `table-layout: fixed` in `.testTable` or one more option there, replace width to max-width in `.testHeader`, we get desire output.it is working fine in chrome, IE and firefox.

for more details about`table-layout: fixed` please refer this link: [click here](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.testBody').scroll(function (e) { 
                $('.testHeader').css("left", -$(".testBody").scrollLeft()); 
                $('.testHeader span:first-child').css("left", $(".testBody").scrollLeft()); 
                $('.testBody span:first-child').css("left", $(".testBody").scrollLeft()); 
                $('.testHeader span:nth-child(2)').css("left", $(".testBody").scrollLeft()); 
                $('.testBody span:nth-child(2)').css("left", $(".testBody").scrollLeft()); 
            });
            var resizeCol = function () {
                //var tiw = $('.table-body .table').width();
                //$('.table-head').width(tiw);
                $('.testBody .testRow:first span').each(function (index, element) {
                    var w = $(this).css('width'),
                        i = $(this).index();
                    //$('.testHeader span:eq(' + i + ')').width(w);                   
                    $('.testHeader span:eq(' + i + ')').css('min-width', w );
                });
            }
            resizeCol();
        });
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.testTable {
    display: table;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.testRow {
    display: table-row;
}

    .testRow > span {
        list-style: none;
        display: table-cell;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 2px 6px;
    }

.testHeader {
    position: relative;
    display: block; /*seperates the header from the body allowing it to be positioned*/
    width: 700px;
    overflow: visible;
    /*display: table-header-group;*/
}

    .testHeader .testRow {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    }

    .testHeader span {
        background: #F9F9F9;
        min-width: 120px;
        height: 32px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
    }

        .testHeader span:first-child {
            position: relative;
            z-index:99;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
        }

        .testHeader span:nth-child(2) {
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
        }

.testBody {
    /*display: table-row-group;*/
    position: relative;
    display: block; /*seperates the tbody from the header*/
    width: 700px;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

    .testBody .testRow:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #fff;
    }

        .testBody .testRow:nth-child(odd) span:nth-child(1) {
            background: #fff;
        }

        .testBody .testRow:nth-child(odd) span:nth-child(2) {
            background: #fff;
        }

    .testBody .testRow:nth-child(even) {
        background: #f9f9f9;
    }

        .testBody .testRow:nth-child(even) span:nth-child(1) {
            background: #f9f9f9;
        }

        .testBody .testRow:nth-child(even) span:nth-child(2) {
            background: #f9f9f9;
        }

    .testBody span {
        min-width: 120px;
        /*max-width:120px;*/      
        word-wrap:break-word;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
    }

        .testBody span:first-child {
            position: relative;
            /*display: block;*/ /*seperates the first column from the tbody*/
            height: 40px;
        }

        .testBody span:nth-child(2) {
            position: relative;
            height: 40px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px;position:relative;">        
            <ul class="testTable" id="table">
                <div class="testHeader">                    
                    <li class="testRow">
                        <span>ID</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                        <span>Description</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                        <span>Details</span>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="testBody">
                    <li class="testRow">
                        <span>1</span>
                        <span>2</span>
                        <span>3 a jghasd kahsdk asd ad as das dsadasdasdasdasdas</span>
                        <span>4</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="testRow">
                        <span>1</span>
                        <span>2</span>
                        <span>3</span>
                        <span>4</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="testRow">
                        <span>1</span>
                        <span>2</span>
                        <span>3</span>
                        <span>4</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                        <span>5</span>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>       
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, its working,  Also in IE there is some flickering happening while scrolling.

Comment: The flickering happens when you scroll by clicking on the scrollbar buttons etc. i IE only.